# Trending tracker in Twitter (Android)

Tags: android, twitter, trading, tracker

I am developing an app which will used for trending tracker in twitter.
The app can open up and show what is trending on twitter, and then you can click on the word that is trending and it will take you to somethings that are being said about it.

I think it's called Trending Tracker.

Please i want to know if you there is an open source code doing this, or a library which can help to do this. Any information will be usable

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great place to start with with the [Twitter API Documentation for Trends](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api#trends)

To get the world-wide trends right now, call

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json
```

That will return the trends, and include a link to the Twitter search page.